# How to print or log the value of CGSize object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I was trying to log (print) the value of CGSize object like this:

```
CGSize sizeOfTab = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width/tabCount, 49);

NSLog(@"size of tab is %@",sizeOfTab);
```

Is there anything wrong in this code; my app is crashing while control comes to NSLog statement.

Thanks
Prasad

Comment: NSStringFromCGSize( ) and also NSStringFromCGRect( )

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can call the following to print the value you are after:

```
NSLog(@"width = %f, height = %f", mySize.width, mySize.height);
```

Answer (score 221):

Try this

```
CGSize sizeOfTab = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width/tabCount, 49);
NSLog(@"size of tab is %@",NSStringFromCGSize(sizeOfTab));
```

The crash occurs because `sizeOfTab` is not in `NSString` format.

Comment: Cool this is something new i learnt today. +1, but i wont delete my answer :-P.

Comment: @Praveen: Thanks.. Glad I cud help you to learn something new today... Just returning the favor. I have been and still in the receiving end of such information through SO.

Comment: @7KV7 The crash occurs because `sizeOfTab` is not an object (any object would work, not just a `NSString`). `CGSize` is a struct.

Comment: thanku its working fine, but its displaying {nan, 49}, what is nan?

Comment: @Prasad: nan I think stands for Not a Number. what is tabCount? try logging `self.frame.size.width/tabCount`

Comment: @7KV7: thanks, Ya if tabCount is zero(0), then its showing nan

Comment: @Prasad: Division by 0 is the problem. As u probably know its not defined hence it shows "nan".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Learned something new :)

Answer (score 11):

As [JoeBlow mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621975/how-to-print-or-log-the-value-of-cgsize-object#comment30397457_6621975) (*I noticed after typing and formatting this answer*), there's also the UIKit function, [`NSStringFromCGSize()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromCGSize), for pretty printing, and its inverse, [`CGSizeFromString()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGSizeFromString), for creating a `CGSize` struct from an `NSString` object.

Apple documents the *`string`* parameter of `CGSizeFromString(`*`string`*`)` as follows:

> A string whose contents are of the form "{*w*, *h*}", where *w* is
>   the width and *h* is the height. The *w* and *h* values can be integer or
>   float values. An example of a valid string is @"{3.0,2.5}". The string
>   is not localized, so items are always separated with a comma.

---

### Example

```
CGSize size = CGSizeFromString(@"{320,568}");
NSLog(@"Pretty printed size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));
```

### Output

`Pretty printed size: {320, 568}`

### Other Useful Functions ([CGGeometry Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html))

- CGRectGetHeight()
- CGRectGetWidth()

Answer (score 6):

%@ means you are trying to insert a string. CGSize is not a string, and cannot automagically be converted to one. That's why your app crashes. Instead, you need to log individual properties separately, like

```
NSLog(@"width is %f, height is %f.", sizeOfTab.width, sizeOfTab.height);
```

%f is used because the *width* and *height* properties are of the type *float*.

For other format conversions, see the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 for a detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks. I had a look around and it's amazing to see how many people never bother looking at the docs before asking a question. I put the link there so we don't get another question asking how to print an _int_.

Answer (score 3):

`CGSize` has the memebers width and height which are of type `CGFloat`. You can print them using the following

```
NSLog(@"Width = %f, height = %f",sizeOfTab.width, sizeofTab.height);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here self.view is the view of UIView Class. You can print any frame with this log.

```
      NSLog(@"self.view.Frame=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));
```